# Mysql sum of field values - count , with group by , order by , limit function

Tags: mysql

I have Table user_views

My Tablet Sample data

```
Id | product_id | category | user_id |  sitename|   price | click_count | created_date
 1     10          watch     102          ebay       820     1            2014-08-18 13:56:05
 2     10          watch     102          amazon     750     1            2014-08-19 13:56:05
 3     10          watch     102          amazon     740     1            2014-08-19 18:00:05
 4     10          watch     102          ebay       940     1            2014-08-25 08:00:00
 5     10          watch     102          amazon     640     5            2014-08-25 08:10:10
 6     10          watch     102          ebay       580     3            2014-09-25 18:10:10
 7     10          watch     102          amazon     980     5            2014-10-05 12:20:40
```

I want the total count of the user visited this product

My Query

```
"select Id , proudct_id , category , user_id , count(click_count) as cnt from user_view where user_id =102 group by product_id order by rand() limit 0,10"
```

But the output is showing only one count

OUTPUT

```
 Id | product_id | category | user_id | cnt
  1     10          watch      102       1
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT IS

```
 Id | product_id | category | user_id |  cnt  
  1     10         watch       102       17
```

Comment: Re-read your title and then look at your code again. Your asking how to calculate the sum; but not using the sum function...

Answer (score 1):

You should be using sum aggregate function instead of count which will count number of rows. So your query should be something like:

```
  select Id , product_id , category , user_id , SUM(click_count) as sum ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select Id , proudct_id , category , user_id , SUM(click_count) as cnt
from user_view
 where user_id =102
order by rand()
limit 0,10
group by product_id
```

`COUNT()` always returns the number of items, not the sum of values. So use `SUM()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
"select Id , proudct_id , category , user_id , count(click_count) as cnt from user_view where user_id =102 group by user_id, product_id order by rand() limit 0,10"
```